# Rails Model with Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails, and below is what I am trying to do.

A model name `experience` with an array attribute call `moments` that will taking string inputs and image input from users.

Base on my readings, it seems like there may be 2 ways to do this:

1. to make my "moment" attribute type array -not sure how to do this yet
2. to create a separate model for 'moment" and then use has_many relationship to link "experience" and "moment" model.

And it seem like 2nd way is the prefer way - as it seems to offer more flexibility in the long term, but I am not 100% sure, anyone care to confirm and explain?

Comment: Yes - you want to go with #2 as most RDBMS systems to not offer an array data type and it starts to potentially violate normal form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association. Even before that, I highly suggest taking a run through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html which includes a walk through to create a few models

Comment: An array column is only useful for a small amount of one-dimensional items/data. Use it for things such as roles, types, etc. your moments will have further data attached, and so should have their own table.